# Is there any point for Cryslons to terraform in Master of Orion?

Tags: master-of-orion-2016

Typically (to the best of my knowledge), terraforming a planet in Master of Orion improves the climate and makes it a better place for farming, hence improved food production. Since the Cryslon's don't require food (eating the planet's mantle instead) I am wondering if it would just be a waste of resources to terraform planets when I am playing as the Cryslon?

Are there any other benefits to terraforming that I am not realizing?

Comment: In the original Master of Orion series, terraforming would also make the planet bigger. (i.e., a larger fraction of the planet is useful.) Even Cryslons found it useful to terraform.

Answer (score 1):

There seems to be no benefit to [terraforming](https://masteroforion.fandom.com/wiki/Terraforming) a planet if it is entirely populated by Silicoid, because it will not improve the mineral composition of the planet. You also gain nothing by building Gravity generator, because they are [not affected by planet size](https://masteroforion.fandom.com/wiki/Silicoid#Characteristics).

You would see a benefit from terraforming if you conquered planets from other races and had a mixed-race planet.